# How to read Consul key value from client?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, consul

Is it possible to re-read custom key/values from consul k/v store with spring-cloud-consul lib? Haven't found an answer in documentation.

Of course it can be accessed with http GET request, but the point is to change some key's value and to make spring application to handle this change immediately.

UPD: unfortunately we've migrated from Consul to config-server, but I guess `@RefreshScope` should do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

spring-cloud-consul auto configures a `ConsulClient` into the application context.  This if from the [Ecwid/consul-api](https://github.com/Ecwid/consul-api) client. Usage is the same, but instead of calling `new ConsulClient()` you would inject one (ie `@Autowired ConsulClient consulClient`).